# Changing JVM settings to fix out-of-memory issues (GC overhead limit) in NetLogo

Tags: java, memory, jvm, netlogo, ram

I've been having some run-out-of-memory problems (GC overhead limit) with my NetLogo model and doing some research I ran into the following info (below). I am not a computer science guy so please excuse me if I am using the wrong terms here, but apparently I can change the RAM storage size so my model doesn't run out of memory (?) However, I have no idea how I should set the new memory threshold level and I wonder if someone could advise me on that? I am currently working on a Win 7 PC with 16 Gb RAM memory (2 8-GB slots and i5 processor), how much do you think I should change the **-Xmx1024m** to? See the reference below:

> **How big can my model be? How many turtles, patches, procedures,**
> **buttons, and so on can my model contain?**
>
> We have tested NetLogo with models that use hundreds of megabytes of
> RAM and they work fine. We haven't tested models that use gigabytes of
> RAM, though. Theoretically it should work, but you might hit some
> limits that are inherent in the underlying Java VM and/or operating
> system (either designed-in limits, or bugs).
>
> The NetLogo engine has no fixed limits on size. By default, though,
> NetLogo ships with a one-gigabyte ceiling on how much total RAM it can
> use. If your model exceeds that limit, you'll get an OutOfMemoryError
> dialog.
>
> If you are using BehaviorSpace, note that doing runs in parallel will
> multiply your RAM usage accordingly.
>
> Each platform contains ".cfg" files containing JVM settings. There is
> one cfg file for each sub-application (NetLogo, NetLogo 3D, HubNet
> Client, etc.) Although the file location varies by platform, the
> process for changing it is the same. Locate the section of the file
> that looks like the following:
>
> **[JVMOptions]**
>
> *[there may be one or more lines, leave them unchanged]*
>
> -Xmx1024m
>
> *[there may be one or more lines, leave them unchanged Modify the value immediately following]*
>
> -Xmx , changing it to the amount of space you need, save the file, and restart NetLogo.

Source: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/

Comment: You have 16 GB so the default maximum heap size is 4 GB. If you are running out of memory, you should either look for a memory leak or increase the maximum heap size, not decrease it.